# Getting average of selected rows for each column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able to get the average of the last 4 rows that are in 'Stage' 2, for each column.

**Sample Data**
[image]

Currently I am using `av = df.loc[df['Stage'] == 2, 'Vout'].mean()` but this gives me the average for the entire column. So for the column vout I am getting the entire columns average value, when I just want the columns average value to be the average of the last 4 rows that are in stage 2.

Comment: `df.loc[df['Stage'].eq(2),'Vout'].tail(4).mean()`?

Answer (score 1):

[@not_speshal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631) has kindly answered my question in the comments.

The solution is to use [`tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tail.html) to select the last 4 rows after `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Stage'].eq(2), 'Vout'].tail(4).mean()
```